# How to get all polygons from a set of points

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry, polygons

I need to get all polygon combinations (convex and concave) from a set of points and don't see the way to do it.

I'm thinking in this two approaches

- Check for each combination to be a planar graph having all nodes grade 2
- Check for each combination not have intersecting vertex (solving equation systems)

Am I right, or absolutely lost?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand the task, the brute force problem scales as (n!)^2 . Hope you have less than 5-6 points, or think of a better alogo them me.

Comment: Thanks george. I know it has high complexity, and I don't need more than 10 points now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that all points have to be in polygon.

On first I would implement [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) approach. Start from one point, add edge to non visited point if it doesn't intersect edges of current path, and repeat while all points are visited. At last, check does edge from first to last path point intersect path.

There are other checks that can be done to remove next edge possible candidates. Find convex hull of all points. Use one point of convex hull as a starting point, and assume that path (polygon) is directed. That means that polygon interior is to the left of the path. Than points on convex hull have to be visited in positive order. That means that last path point can't be connected to convex point except one after (anti-clockwise directed) last visited. With this check, input set of points where all points are convex hull points (e.g. regular n-gon), will produce search tree of width 1 (list). Since it is not possible to create concave polygon if all points are on convex hull, because any connection between two non-neighbors split set of points in the way that there can't be edge between these two parts without intersecting that edge.

Comment: note backtracking will find each polygon twice (one the reverse of the other).  You could probably make use of that to gain a bit of efficiency.

Comment: It will not find polygon twice since path defines polygon with orientation. Polygon is on the left side of the path. ABC is different triangle than ACB, or only one can be a triangle.

Comment: I was refering to the simple approach in your first paragraph.  Of course hitting the convex hull in order takes care of that problem(Really good observation by the way+1).

Comment: @george Thanks. I think it is still possible to prune search tree. By checking 'visibility' of not visited points. If, while adding new edge to the path, we have for each not visited point list of visible not visited points from it. Than, if new edge removes all visible points from one point, we know it can't be sub-path of solution. That will not increase complexity of tree search, but it will add O(n^4) of edge-edge intersection pre-processing.